# How is this generating an image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I went through the GAN network using tensorflow in [tensorflow official site](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/generative/dcgan#the_generator).

Here I came across this point

```py
generator = make_generator_model()

noise = tf.random.normal([1, 100])
generated_image = generator(noise, training=False)

plt.imshow(generated_image[0, :, :, 0], cmap='gray')
```

The make generator_model() returns a sequential model. Yeah, that's cool. But what about the generated_image? Isn't it the tensor value? How can we just generate image and check them when we have not run the session and how is that the matplotlib pyplot function is plotting on tensor object? It should be numpy and as far as I know, pyplot accepts numpy array to plot an image. Isn't it? Can anyone help me regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0):

That method is defined as

```
 def make_generator_model():
     model = tf.keras.Sequential()
     model.add(layers.Dense(4*4*1024, use_bias = False, input_shape = (100,)))
     model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
     model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())
```

As you can see, what you get is a `tf.keras.Sequential`

### Dense Layer

In Keras, you can create layers to develop models. A model is usually a network of layers, in which, the most common type is a stack of layers

Adding a densely-connected layer to the model will take as input arrays of shape (*, 100). The shape of the data will be (*, 4*4*1024) after the first layer. In this case, you won’t need to specify the size of the input moving forward because of automatic shape inference

Batch normalization functions similarly to preprocessing at every layer of the network.

ReLU is linear for all positive values and set to zero for all negative values. Leaky ReLU has a smaller slope for negative values, instead of altogether zero.

For example, leaky ReLU may have y = 0.01x when x < 0

More info https://towardsdatascience.com/developing-a-dcgan-model-in-tensorflow-2-0-396bc1a101b2

Comment: You are not explaining the question mate. The question is, how can it generate image when it returns a tensor  without running the session ?

Comment: It's random noise and the noise is generated in the contents of the make_generator_model method. It's partially explained in my answer and the rest in the link provided but didn't want to copy the whole blog post.

Comment: Thanks for that actually. But I know we do that we random noise. But we have not run the session right? When we run the code in my jupyter notebook, it doesn't generate image as it says it is tensor object. How can I solve that?

Comment: If you copy paste the code from the link you pasted and run it, it should work

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial uses TF 2.0 which employs *eager execution* by default. This means that ops are run as they are defined, similar to e.g. PyTorch. Because of this, you can think about control flow in a much more "natural" way (such as numpy functions). Calling `generator` immediately returns a tensor with values (which `plt.imshow` converts to a numpy array), there are no more sessions. I encourage you to check out the tutorials on the TF website that talk about the 2.0 changes.